# Get and use user data from another sheet in Google Docs

Tags: user-controls, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We use google spreadsheets for reporting by quite a big number of users.
I have written a basic script, which opens a specific sheet depending on the current user:

```
var CurrentUser = Session.getUser().getEmail()
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  switch(CurrentUser){
    case "usermail1@gmail.com":
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"));
      break;
    case "usermail2@gmail.com":
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("sheet2"));
      break;
    case "usermail3@gmail.com":
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("sheet3"));
      break;
    etc...
```

I would like to put the userdata and sheetnames into an external table and get these data depending on that table, so it is easier to maintain the list of e-mails and users.
How can I get data from a specific google spreadsheet and let the script work according to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It simulates a `VLOOKUP` on a different sheet and switches to the 'matched' sheet in your current workbook. This doesn't handle non-matches, but that should be relatively straightforward to add to suit your case.

```js
function switchSheets() {
  // Current sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // Target sheet (using the key found in the URL)
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my_other_sheet_id");
  var rows = target.getDataRange();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  // Get the current user
  var CurrentUser = Session.getUser().getEmail();

  // Now iterate through all of the rows in your target sheet,
  // looking for a row that matches your current user (this assumes that
  // it will find a match - you'll want to handle non-matches as well)
  for (var i = 1; i <= rows.getNumRows() - 1; i++) {
    // Match the leftmost column
    var row = values[i][0];
    if (row == CurrentUser) {
      // If we match, grab the corresponding sheet (one column to the right)
      target_sheet = values[i][1];
      break;
    }
  }
  // Now switch to the matched sheet (rememeber to handle non-matches)
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(target_sheet));
};
```